# Twitter Bootstrap 3.0 Responsive IMG Height Issue

Tags: css, image, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm building a quick HTML prototype in Twitter Bootstrap 3 and hit a small snag with the height of a responsive image.

I defined three columns across with an image in each column. I set the images to be responsive and modified the padding in between each column from default bootstrap. My problem is the image in the center column is slightly larger than the images in the column to the left and right of it. Here's a quick screenshot of my problem: http://d.pr/i/z5AS

How can I fix so that all three images in each column are the same height?

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 item-left">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="img/twitter-android.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 item-center">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="img/twitter-android.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 item-right">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="img/twitter-android.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
}
.item-left {
    padding-right: 1px;
}
.item-center {
    padding: 0 1px;
}
.item-right {
    padding-left: 1px;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated on this!

Comment: can you provide the image path

Comment: This doesn't solve your problem, but your CSS for **img** duplicates styling which is automatically put in by bootstrap for the **img-responsive** class, so there is no point in it being there.

Comment: Does this problem occur in all browsers or just (say) IE. It sounds more like a browser specific problem with padding and margins to me *cough* Internet Explorer *cough*

Comment: I think I figured it out. By default the columns have padding left/right of 15px. In the CSS above I stripped the padding left/right from the image in the center column, but not from the images in the left/right column. I added padding-left: 0px to item-left and padding-right: 0px to item-right and that did the trick.

Comment: Screenshot link is dead. Will change downvote to upvote if fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're coming across is fairly simple to fix, although without the actual markup, and the CSS you've used to overwrite the default Bootstrap behaviour in resizing the columns, I can't give you an exact fix.

Basically: the reason the middle image is appearing bigger than the other two is because the middle column is - one way or the other - very slightly wider than the two outer columns.

So, when you apply `max-width: 100%` to the images, they are all flowing to the full width of their column.  The middle one being slightly wider means that the image itself scales up slightly more than the other two.

Use Firebug/INspector to identify why that middle column is wider and you'll have your answer!

Answer (score 0):

I made a small tweak to the style using `max-width`, but controlled the height by setting the `min-height` and `max-height` property.
https://github.com/Gregory-Phillips/twitter-bootstrap-sandbox/blob/master/imageHeight.html
I placed the override above the closing `</head>` just to keep it in a visible area. It seems to keep the responsive nature... Maybe this is what you could look at?

Answer (score 0):

because Image will be resize according to col-sm4 width. and also you have use padding-left:15px; padding-right:1px on left column.
padding-right:15px; padding-left:1px on right column.
in both cases, images will be squezze/resize because of giving padding

but in the middle image. you have given padding only 1px  from left and right. notice that image will be squezze/resize less in comparison other images.

so if you want images size should be equal  then **you have to give equal padding from left and right side on 3 images.**